# Converting disparity map to 3D points

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have a disparity map of an image .I need to convert it to a set of 3D points and normals.How can I do this and is there any such existing implementation which can do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Gnu Triangulated Surface](http://gts.sourceforge.net/) library?

When I've did this before I had a depth-map (or disparity map if you prefer) and - knowing the original camera calibration - was able to perform the re-projection back into R3 for the points.

Knowing the neighbourhood of each point (by their original neighbouring pixels) it's quite trivial to then create a basic triangulation to connect them up.

(If you didn't know this you would have to attempt some form of Delaunay triangulation or other more advanced algorithm...)

Make sure you get the vertex order correct for each triangle to ensure all the normals point the correct way/consistently.

[Meshlab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) is quite handy for any additional post processing.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at this OpenCV function: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#reprojectimageto3d

Comment: If you only need to have the 3d point this function can be improved in speed... if you need it, vote up and I will add the speed code.

Answer (score 1):

```
        cvFindStereoCorrespondenceBM( frame1r, frame2r, disp, BMState);

        /*      cvShowImage("camera1", frame1);
                cvShowImage("camera2", frame2);         */      
        //      cvConvertScale( disp, disp, 16, 0 );
                cvNormalize( disp, vdisp, 0, 256, CV_MINMAX );                   
                cvShowImage( "disparity", vdisp );              
                cvReprojectImageTo3D(disp, Image3D, &_Q);               
                cvShowImage("depthmap",Image3D);
```

this code snippet would help you I hope. Here explanation of code is as follows: When I rectify the images from right and left cameras and defining the `BMstate` I have passed this into  `cvFindStereoCorrespondenceBM` to find the disparity image. Next defining a matrix of dimension 3 to store the 3D points as `Image3D`.  By the function in opencv `cvReprojectImageTo3D`  passing the Q matrix which we obtain in stereo correspondence we obtain the Set of 3D points corresponding to that 2D image

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if it explained _why_ it is a helpful thing to do; virtually pure code snippets tend to not get a lot of upvotes.

Comment: Donald Fellows ,Edited the explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
 @ here is calculation which may help  you 

  % %Z = fB/d
  % where
  % Z = distance along the camera Z axis
  % f = focal length (in pixels)
  % B = baseline (in metres)
  % d = disparity (in pixels) 
  % % After Z is determined, X and Y can be calculated using the usual projective         camera equations:
 % 
  % X = uZ/f
  % Y = vZ/f

 % where
 % u and v are the pixel location in the 2D image
 % X, Y, Z is the real 3d position

  % Note: u and v are not the same as row and column. You must account for the image   center. You can get the image center using the triclopsGetImageCenter() function. Then you find u and v by:

  % u = col - centerCol
  % v = row - centerRow

  % Note: If u, v, f, and d are all in pixels and X,Y,Z are all in the meters, the units will always work i.e. pixel/pixel = no-unit-ratio = m/m.
```

Comment: it would be better to add some explanation with the code. SO is not a "code library", but a helping site. Adding explanation is the best way to answer a question not only the code matters, but how is it working and the working principle are as important as the solution to a problem.